# Office 2016 program shortcuts

Tags: shortcuts, file-shortcut

I have deleted some of Office 2016 shortcuts by mistake. Now I want to have them back, but I'm not able to restore the advertised shortcuts. The only solution has been creating a normal shortcut and pasting it in Start Menu.

Any idea on how to restore the original ones? I have even tried to get them from another computer, but it seems that the original ones are signed or something else.

Comment: Shortcuts are not signed.  Have you tried to simply repair your Office 2016 installation?

Comment: No I haven't. I have the suite properly configured now and I don't want the repair process to remove my configuration. I think I'm gonna live with the normal shortcut.

Comment: What is the difference between the shortcuts you deleted and the “normal shortcut”?